# Dodge Ram 1500, 2003 oil leaking from exhaust manifold

Tags: dodge, ram, exhaust-manifold

I recently had a mechanic replace the exhaust manifolds on my Dodge Ram 1500, 2003.

Since I got it back I noticed oil leaking from bolt numbers 5 and 6 on the manifold diagram.

[image: manifold diagram]

I can see the oil bubbling around the head of the bolt and dripping down the manifold.

[image: manifold]

I know the mechanic had to break the bolts to get the manifold off.  He was able to use an extractor to remove the bolts; didn't have to retap, use a helicoil, or anything like that.  It didn't leak before I had the manifold replaced.

Why is there oil leaking from around these bolts if this is the exhaust?

Update:
Last night I removed and reinserted bolt #5. There was Aluminum anti-seize on the bolt.  I don't know what the torque spec is, nor do I have a torque wrench that would fit into this space, so I just tightened it.  It appears to have slowed the leaking some, I don't see any bubbling around the bolt head any longer, but there is a steady drip from #6 bolt.